# Formulating TSQL Left Join

Tags: t-sql, join

I am using SSMS 2008.  Should be a simple solution to this.  I am trying to pull all records from table A, but only pull in matching records from tables B and C.  The problem is that if I left join tables B and C, it returns records where all 3 of these tables intersect instead.  Like if I query this combined merge, I get non-NULL values for every row for both B and C.

Here is my pseudocode:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, C.ID
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN C ON C.ID = A.ID
```

In answer to your questions, I am sorry I forgot the "LEFT", but I just added it above.  If table A has 9 rows and B has 2 rows and C has 3 rows, then what I want to see above is where table A intersects B and where A intersects C.
So in the scenario just described, assuming that the Table B rows are all different than the Table C rows, then I want to see a total of 5 rows; 2 from B and 3 from C.  Make sense?

Comment: Your pseudo code doesn't seem to make sense. Please provide example data and desired results. Specifically if `B` has 3 matches for a row in `A` and `C` has 2 matches for the same row what do the desired results look like?

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear.  You state you want to pull all records from table A but then then state it is a problem when the left outer join returns all records.  Have you tested the pseudocode?  Does it not return the desired results?  The pseudocode represents A with matching records in B AND matching records in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way to do this is with a `LEFT JOIN`.  I believe (though it's unclear from your question) that the problem you have is multiple rows per `A.ID`.

If `A.ID` matches `B.ID` **AND** `C.ID` then you are getting two rows for this, and would like one consolidated row.

I think maybe you had your `JOIN` conditions mixed up in your test query.  This is working fine for me in testing.  Try the below query:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (ID INT)
DECLARE @B TABLE (ID INT)
DECLARE @C TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO @A VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4)

INSERT INTO @B VALUES
(2),
(3)

INSERT INTO @C VALUES
(3),
(4)

SELECT A.ID, B.ID, C.ID
FROM @A A
LEFT JOIN @B B
    ON B.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN @C C
    ON C.ID = A.ID
```

Output is:

```
ID  ID      ID
1   NULL    NULL
2   2       NULL
3   3       3
4   NULL    4
```

Comment: Thank you all for your helps!  I actually fixed this problem by left joining tables A and B and then A and C and just UNIONing the results together.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is a join to a union stamtement.

```
SELECT A.ID, 
case when D.tablename = 'B' then  ID else null end, 
case when D.tablename = 'C' then  ID else null end
FROM A 
JOIN 
(select Id, 'b' as tablename from B
union all
select id, 'c' from c)
D ON D.ID = A.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is still inconsistent.  I think you mean where table A intersects B OR where A intersects C.  In that case the proper TSQL is:

```
    SELECT A.ID
    FROM A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON C.ID = A.ID
    WHERE B.ID IS NOT NULL OR C.ID IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY A.ID 
    ORDER BY A.ID
```

No need to report B.ID and C.ID if they equal A.ID. 
Group By is so you don't get repeated A.ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, C.ID
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN C ON C.ID = A.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NOT NULL OR C.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Or, if you need only fields from A, then

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT B.ID FROM B
    UNION
    SELECT C.ID FROM C ) AS U ON U.ID = A.ID
```